# How do I toggle class correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I'm trying to toggle two classes but it's not working.

HTML

```
 <a class="reme" href="#"><i class="far fa-circle"></i> Remember Me</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".reme").click(function() {

 if ( $(this).toggleClass( 'i' ) == ( 'far fa-circle' ))  {

 $( 'i' ).toggleClass( 'fas fa-circle' );

 } else {

  $( 'i' ).toggleClass( 'far fa-circle' );

 }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`toggleClass` basically adds a class in the list if it is not present or removes it if it is. You'll be able to remove the code for `addClass` & `removeClass`.

It looks like you don't want to change whether or not `fa-circle` is there, so you can remove that from `toggleClass`. This should leave you with only needing this:

```
$(".reme").click(function() {
    $( "i" ).toggleClass("far fas");
});
```

This will toggle between `far` & `fas`. For example, if the current element was `<i class="fa-circle far"></i>` & the click event happens, the element will become `<i class="fa-circle fas"></i>`.

The documentation can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: This toggle between `class="far fas"` and `class=""`

Comment: @JacobLamb Here's a jsFiddle showing how it should be working: https://jsfiddle.net/4bxrwkgs/ Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @ThomasByy It should only do that if `far` & `fas` are both present or missing as classes. Otherwise it should swap between them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```js
$(".reme").click(function() {
  if ( $( this ).find('i').hasClass( "far" ) ) {
      $( this ).find('i').removeClass( "far" );
      $( this ).find('i').addClass( "fas" );
    } else {
      $( this ).find('i').removeClass( "fas" );
      $( this ).find('i').addClass( "far" );
    }
});
```

```css
.far { color:red; }
.fas { color:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a class="reme" href="#"><i class="far fa-circle">X</i> Remember Me</a>
  <a class="reme" href="#"><i class="far fa-circle">X</i> Remember Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using **toggleClass** to add and remove both **far** and **fas** classes alternatively

```
$('i').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('fas far');
});
```

Reference link for more details on toggleClass- https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/
working code sample for reference
codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RXRPry

```js
$('i').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('fas far');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="reme" href="#">
  <i class="far fa-circle"></i> 
  Remember Me
</a>
```